# How to develop plugins for the native Android browser

Tags: android, plugins, browser

I searched the web but no luck: how can plugins for the native Android browser be developed?! Neither Google nor the Android SDK give information about this topic.

Comment: What kind of thing are you looking to implement?

Comment: a plugin that allows to download the current HTML for further processing.

Comment: I've written a guide which I hope will be helpful, please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15244703/2138979

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a sample of a plugin in the Android source code under `development/samples/BrowserPlugin`.

So I guess `development/samples/BrowserPlugin/README` should be a good start.

Comment: The activity class is SamplePlugin (for eclipse quick open resource)

Comment: This sample has been removed from AOSP 2.3 (Gingerbread) - possibly unintentionally (since the [commit which removed it](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/development.git;a=commit;h=dede009a98b805967f280d03d8bdec8422bde25e) has "do not merge" in the title).

If you have the Gingerbread android source code locally, you can get the BrowserPlugin project like this:
`cd development/samples`
`git checkout 48c0834ab556185d734e19b679fdc4af99b0de3a BrowserPlugin`

Comment: I don't even see a development folder in the source...? http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/

Comment: Maybe it has been removed, I found a mirror of the code here: https://www.codeaurora.org/git/projects/qrd-gb-dsds-7225/repository/revisions/cc99b832a941dc8cbb86f1607d04eb87935ddbfd/show/android/development/samples/BrowserPlugin

Comment: A live link: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/BrowserPlugin/