# Plugin for Android Browser

Tags: android, plugins, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop plugins for the native Android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960050/how-to-develop-plugins-for-the-native-android-browser)

I want to develop the plugin for android browser, it will be installed on device. whenever user browse some thing on browser my plugin will run and give the appropriate response to browser UI.

I have few questions on it:
1. Is it possible to develop such plugins for android browser, if so pls suggest any  link/code for development.
2. How much possibilities are there with WebView.

Other idea/trick is it possible?:
There will be my native application which is installed on device and it will communicate with android browser and listen the activities going on it.Then application will pass required values to browser.

Thanks,
siddh