# Accessing cell number in mobile website

Tags: javascript

Is there a way I can access mobile number of the phone through which I am accessing the web page?

Is there any open source JavaScript API to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take stab at this and say that its not possible.  If it were that would be a huge breach of privacy on the phones.  Also see here

[Retrieve IMEI number/ sim number/mobile number via mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413305/retrieve-imei-number-sim-number-mobile-number-via-mobile-browser)