# Is it possible to access cell number in mobile website with user permission?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

[I have read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177885/accessing-cell-number-in-mobile-website) and I know that I cannot directly access cell phone number in mobile website. However, is there a way I can access it with user's permission?

I am creating a mobile website of a member program. To register, I will need to verify the mobile number by sending a sms. Sending sms cost a lot, especially if the user is from another country. So I am thinking of another way to verify the user's mobile number, and one way I can think of is to get the mobile number from mobile browser with user's permission. Is this possible or do I have other ways to verify user's mobile number without sending a sms?

I am using PHP with laravel for backend but are willing to switch to any other language or framework if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Browsers offer no such API.

Comment: @RononDex — It does answer the question. It might not provide an answer that is desired. What is being asked for is simply impossible. There is no critique or request for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

**NO** you can not.

you can prompt the user to enter their phone number and trust that they will enter the correct number then get that number using a HTTP-Get or HTTP-POST at your server side