# IMEI in HTML website

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, imei

How can I know the IMEI of the mobile,

via an **HTML** site

Without using PhoneGap?

Comment: That's already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413305/retrieve-imei-number-sim-number-mobile-number-via-mobile-browser

Comment: via an HTML site --> in JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a phone, only native app can have access to the IMEI number, not web apps. So the browser may have access if it has enough permissions but this information is not provided to the page. This is intentional because many things can be achieved by the site owner like tracking and for ads.

So, if you really want to have the IMEI, you would need to create a native app (like PhoneGap which you have said no to) and get permissions. If your intention is just to track the user in your site, you can assign a unique id for him/her in a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

It is an epic opportunity for browsers to bridge the native divide by proxying permissions to deliver native functionality to pages.

Just as they ASK for permission to use mic/camera then can easily do the same for other Phone functions and resources. I am after ICCID && IMEI via JS !!

The browser then becomes the SuperAPP. Why this has not yet been done is really surprising.  There is a movement toward cross-platform with FLUTTER and React Native Web (RNW) however the plugin support is at this stage dismal.