# How to get IMEI number in Windows mobile web application

Tags: asp.net, windows-mobile

I'm developing a WEB application for windows mobile devices in Visual studio. I need to identify the user's device IMEI number. Please help me how to do it.

Comment: Try the links reported on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702868/serial-number-of-phone-device

Comment: But i'm using a web application. It's basically a webpage. not an application.

Comment: If I assume a Windows Phone or Windows Mobile OS, then there is no standard WEB SDK that delivers that information to the client browser. For security, the client browser has no direct access to the hardware or file system. For Windows Mobile (up to 6.5.x) you need to have a custom ActiveX installed to get the hardware information. On Windows Phone OS (7,8,10) there is no way due to the sandbox except the OEM does provide a special SDK. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139390/imei-in-html-website and look for WAP security holes.

Answer (score 0):

I found that we cant access IMEI number of windows mobile using web application. But i think it would be possible if i create an application for windowsmobile and get the IMEI using that app and load the web application into the same app and pass the IMEI to the web application.