# How to detct mobile number via mobile browserr?

Tags: javascript, android, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following is the scenario: I have an web application accessible via mobile browser. I need to detect a mobile number whenever an user open my web site using their mobile and automatic sign in using that mobile number

```
localhost:3000
you are sign in using u r mobile number "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

like

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413305/retrieve-imei-number-sim-number-mobile-number-via-mobile-browser
```

in ruby on rails

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. *Fortunately*. Imagine the HUGE security breach this would be. Any web advertiser would love to find such a way to get your phone number.

EDIT: While there are some HTTP header fields that are thought to contain that information, they are *luckily* not implemented in most browsers, so don't work reliably.

Comment: It is possible, Advertising firms use it to provide customized ads. I learnt about it in a recent Media Summit here at my place. You can check this: http://mobiforge.com/design-development/useful-x-headers `x-up-calling-line-id: End users phone number`

Comment: Although not completely revealed here is a short intro: http://ibsunified.com/hyper-personalized-facebook-ads/

Comment: But those fields are not implemented in most Android browsers, are they?

Comment: My Bad, I answered in a generalized manner. I wanted to impress upon the possibility of can be done or not.

Comment: Happy coding matey :)

Comment: one more doubts if i create one android app for geeting mobile number .is it possible to call that android apps while loading my website