# How to Read device IMEI Using Angular 2 Web URL

Tags: android, angular, web, https

I am trying to get Android Device `IMEI` number using Angular2 Web URL. In my scenario, i have configured physical web and notified the particular URL on device, once the URL is clicked by user the URL then sends device details like (`imei`,`model`,`serial`) to server using Angular2. 
Is this Possible?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: This is impossible for very good security reasons, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413305/retrieve-imei-number-sim-number-mobile-number-via-mobile-browser for more details.