# "Toasting" in android webbrowser?

Tags: android, browser, web, toast

Is it possible to create a toast-message that gets displayed in the default android webbrowser?.. or does "toasting" only work with custom WebViews?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Toasting is not a part of custom Web Views. It just works everywhere inside your apk file. If you like to toast a message when web browser is on, I think you should write an Android service that keeps track of active applications.

- There is a toast-like message jquery plugin on [this](http://www.ashishblog.com/blog/display-notification-messages-using-jquery/) link
- If you have your own custom web view, you can make javascript enabled. You can take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) link.

P.S : I believe you are not developing a native android application.

Comment: So... basically I can´t just do a toast-message by simply using javascript or something?..

Comment: if you're using jquery, there is a toast message plugin http://www.ashishblog.com/blog/display-notification-messages-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add some functionality to the default browser. I'd recommend you consider trying to write a browser plugin: [How to develop plugins for the native Android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960050/how-to-develop-plugins-for-the-native-android-browser)