# Mobile browsers plugins implementation

Tags: android, ios, internet-explorer, google-chrome, mozilla

I need to implement my own plugins into android/iOS browsers. Do you know is there some opportunity for this to be done? (like for Mozilla, IE, Chrome and so on). Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about the stock (OOB) browsers:

**Windows Phone:** No

**Android:** Not really (refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960050/how-to-develop-plugins-for-the-native-android-browser))

**iOS:** No

You can, however, develop applications that register for specific types or file associations, that can be launched when the browser encounters a certain file that is not handled by the OS.

Comment: You can create extensions on [Firefox for Android](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/).

Answer (score 0):

You can develop [mobile extensions on Firefox for Android](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/). I don't think that other mobile browsers support extensions.